# Adding the full name to the left hand side of 'List of Figures' and 'List of Tables'

Tags: table-of-contents

I'd like to add 'Figure X' and 'Table X' in my lists on Latex, and currents only 'X' is displayed (on the left hand side). See reference below.

[image]

Any pointers on how to make this simple change please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tocloft` package; to read the manual `texdoc tocloft`.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }% put Figure before figure number
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{3em}% extra space for Figure (adjust to suit)
% and similarly for Tables, replacing fig above with tab
% and Figure with Table
```